# Why is JSLint giving me an "Unexpected '.'" error with this code?

Tags: javascript, html, phpstorm, jslint

JSLint is giving me an "Unexpected '.'" error with this code on line 2 (with the for loop), and it stops scanning the file at this point as well.

```
var form = document.form1;
for (var i=0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
  // inner-loop code not included here
}
```

I checked in the Developer Console in Chrome, and form.elements does contains what I'd expect. Why is JSLint giving me this error?

I'm using JSLint through PhpStorm.

Comment: Which line does it complain about? You are showing us multiple lines with `.` in them.

Comment: Crockford suggests that all declarations happen at the top of a function. `var form = document.form1, i = 0;` and change `i++` to `i += 1`

Comment: Do you have code in your for loop between `{...}` ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera yes, it's long so I didn't include it.

Comment: @robbmj moving declarations to the top and changing `i++` to `i += 1`did not solve the issue.

Comment: odd, I just tried it and lint is not giving me the unexpected dot error, but is giving me the error about variable declarations.

Comment: The code you've posted does not reproduce your issue at www.jslint.com, but it does produce about 7 other errors.

Comment: This script is within a script tag in an html document. This error is not given after moving the code into a separate .js file. Could using JSLint on an html document be the cause?

Comment: it seems the problem might be on the PhpStorm side

Comment: @JaakKütt It's entirely possible. I'll probably end up leaving the code this code in a separate .js file.

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to reproduce your issue in JSLint. However, since JS does not have block scope and instead function scope, JSLint ([Doug Crockford](http://www.crockford.com/)) recomends all variable declaration happen at the top of the function.

Also he recommends not using the `++` operator and instead to `+= 1`. Try the below code in JSLint and make sure "assume browser" is set to true

```
function foo() {
    'use strict';

    var form = document.form1,
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i += 1) {
        window.console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We need more information to really answer this. The HTML and the all the JS. If it's too long to post in the body of the question you could try hosting it at a service like http://jsfiddle.net/

Without being able to reproduce it I'm going to guess that `document.form1` isn't what you want. Perhaps you meant `document.forms`. That gives access to all the forms in the DOM as an htmlCollection, which you access like an array. For example `document.forms[1]`. Read more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.forms